# selecting entries by a particular day in Oracle

Tags: oracle, days

I have been trying to search for all entries on a Sunday from a table without any success.

The select and from sections work fine and produce a list or all appointment numbers and all days, but I dont seem able to just list those from sundays.
I have rearranged the `WHERE` in every way I can think might work but either get errors or no rows returned.

```
select AppointmentNo, TO_CHAR(AppointmentDate,'DAY') as AppDate  
from Appointment  
where TO_CHAR(AppointmentDate,'DAY') = 'SUNDAY'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably trim the output before comparing.

```
select AppointmentNo, TO_CHAR(AppointmentDate,'DAY') as AppDate
from Appointment
where trim(TO_CHAR(AppointmentDate,'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'
```

Comment: that works great  
thanks :)  
prety new at this & didnt know about the trim

Comment: Could you please select this as an answer? I'm shamelessly trying to build my reputation :)

Comment: selected.. i think :) - new here & didnt see how to select